# Что не так в коде этой программы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача:

Имеется список людей с указанием их фамилии, имени и даты рождения. Напишите эффективную по времени работы и по используемой памяти программу, которая будет определять самого старшего человека из этого списка и выводить его фамилию и имя и дату рождения, а если имеется несколько самых старших людей с одинаковой датой рождения, то определять их количество.

**Входные данные**
На вход программе в первой строке подается количество людей в списке N. В каждой из последующих N строк находится информация в следующем формате: <Фамилия> <Имя> <Дата рождения>, где <Фамилия> – строка, состоящая не более, чем из 20 символов без пробелов, <Имя> – строка, состоящая не более, чем из 20 символов без пробелов, <Дата рождения> – строка, имеющая вид ДД.ММ.ГГГГ, где ДД – двузначное число от 01 до 31, ММ – двузначное число от 01 до 12, ГГГГ – четырехзначное число от 1800 до 2100.

**Выходные данные**
Программа должна вывести фамилию и имя самого старшего человека в списке и его дату рождения. Если таких людей, несколько, то программа должна вывести их количество.

**Примеры**
вход:
3
Ivan Ivanov 01.10.1995
Lena Ivanovna 04.10.1999
Kolya Chernov 10.10.2010

выход:
Ivan Ivanov 01.10.1995

вход:
3
Ivan Ivanov 03.10.1997
Lena Ivanovna 03.10.1997
Kolya Chernov 03.10.1997

выход:
3

Написал на python3 код

```
from datetime import date 
age_days = []
doball=[]
name=[]

n = int(input())

for _ in range(n):
    nahme, nadme, dob = input().split()
    nahme+=" "+nadme+" "+dob

    name = nahme.split(" ")
    doball.append(dob)
    d, m, y = map(int, dob.split("."))
    days = (date.today() - date(y, m, d)).days
    age_days.append((" ".join(name), days))



max_val = max(age_days, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
max_names=[name for name, days in age_days if days== max_val]




if len(max_names) == 1:
    print(max_names[0])

else:
    print(len(max_names))
```

тестирование выдает 4 теста из 20 что не так?

Comment: `name=[]` не нужно.

Comment: старайтесь использовать заголовок вопроса более специфичный для вашей задачи "Что не так в коде этой программы" -- это чересчур общий заголовок [ask]

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime

min_d = datetime.date(datetime.MAXYEAR, 12, 31)
counter = 0

n = int(input())

for _ in range(n):
    input_ = input()
    birthday_str = input_.split()[-1]
    birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(birthday_str, '%d.%m.%Y').date()
    if counter and birthday == min_d:
        counter += 1
    elif birthday < min_d:
        counter = 1
        min_d = birthday
        name_older = input_

result_str = name_older if counter == 1 else str(counter)
print(result_str)
```